# Meteor retrieving document _id from reactive table

Tags: meteor

I am using [Reactive-Table](https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/reactive-table) to display data saved in my Meteor app as shown from the code below, in each row of the table there is a link to edit the document related to this row. I am trying using the edit link 'click event' to capture the _id of the document related to the row being selected but can't seem to get the _id, can someone please check my code and let me know what I am missing / doing wrong here and how to capture the _id? Thanks

customerslist.html

```
<template name="customerslist">
  <div class="customerslist">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Customers List</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      {{> reactiveTable class="table table-bordered table-hover" collection=customersCollection settings=settings}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

customerslist.js

```
Template.customerslist.helpers({
    customersCollection: function () {
        return Customers.find({},{sort: {title: 1}});
    },
    settings: function () {
        return {
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            showFilter: true,
            showColumnToggles: false,
            fields: [
          { key: 'name', label: 'Customer Name' },
          { key: 'email', label: 'Email' },          
          { key: 'phone', label: 'Phone' },
          { key: '_id', label: 'Action', sortByValue: false, fn: function(_id){ return new Spacebars.SafeString('<a name="' + _id +'" class="edtlnk" target="_blank" href="' + _id + '/edit"> Edit </a>'); }  }
      ]
        };
    }
});

Template.customerslist.customers = function () {
    return Customers.find({},{sort: {title: 1}});
};

Template.customerslist.events({    
   'click .edtlnk': function(e) {
      var cust = this;
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('Customer ID: '+cust._id);    
   }          
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The way the package sets up data contexts, `this` will only be set to the customer object if the event selector matches the tr element. That makes event.currentTarget the tr, but event.target is still the edit link.

You could try something like this:

```
Template.customerslist.events({    
   'click .customerslist tr': function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('edtlnk')) {
            var cust = this;
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Customer ID: '+cust._id);  
        }
   }          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Meteor though I am starting to play around with it so I don't care about up or down votes at all but learning the answer your question.

**I found the Event Maps docs** which I am sure you saw as well:
https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps

**This was listed in the doc:**

```
{
  'click p': function (event) {
    var paragraph = event.currentTarget; // always a P
    var clickedElement = event.target; // could be the P or a child element
  }
}
```

If a selector matches multiple elements that an event bubbles to, it will be called multiple times, for example in the case of 'click
div' or 'click *'. If no selector is given, the handler will only be called once, on the original target element.

The following properties and methods are available on the event object passed to handlers:

type String
The event's type, such as "click", "blur" or "keypress".

**target DOM Element**
The element that originated the event.

**currentTarget DOM Element**
The element currently handling the event. This is the element that matched the selector in the event map. For events that bubble, it may be target or an ancestor of target, and its value changes as the event bubbles.

***It seems to me that since target and currentTarget are DOM elements can't you get what you need from those or are you referring to the _id available in Meteor on an insert callback?***